# How do I default sub-module versions in a Maven multi-module project using snapshots?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, snapshot, maven-release-plugin, parent-pom

I looked at previous questions on the topic and it seems people were a step ahead of where am I at the moment.
I am currently trying to use the maven release plugin to my multi module project. I start from scratch (more exactly, I retrieved some old projects to put in a new multi module project).

I have a POM parent that I defines as:

```
<groupId>com.somestuff</groupId>
<artifactId>stuff</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name> stuff </name>
```

My child modules inherits the parent using:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somestuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>stuff</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

So since it’s a new project, I specify the dependencies between modules as snapshots. For example, if module A depends on module B, I will add to A’s POM the part:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somestuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>divarmiclient</artifactId>
     <version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT </version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The result is when I try to do a “mvn release:prepare”, Maven will yell that there is snapshot dependencies. But since it’s a whole new project, and that versions prior to 10 don’t exist, I have no idea how to default the version values of the modules.
My question is, how shall I default the module values ? How do I do in order to make my multi-module project acceptable from a snapshot perspective ?

Comment: I hope your parent contains `<modules><module>divarmiclient</module>/<modules>` ?

Comment: Yes it does, and all the other modules.

Comment: If this is the way i would assume something else is wrong but i can't guess without the whole pom files...

Answer (score 7):

For clarification, you're saying your structure is:

```
theparent
  pom.xml
  A/
    pom.xml
  B/
    pom.xml
```

And the following assumptions all hold true:

- theparent, A, and B are currently on same version
- releases will always be kicked off from 'theparent' level so they *remain* on same version
- A depends on B, always same version

Then the solution is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.somestuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
 <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```